# c++ constant type conversion in arithmetics

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang-extensions

## Background

I am trying to learn in C++11 with clang on mac.

## Question

As it is said in the book, when float type meets int or lower case in arithmetic, the latter will be converted to float. It is true in cases like:

```
cout << 9.0 / 5 << endl;
```

The result yields `1.8000`, but when I try to use suffix to ensure the type for the constants like:

```
cout << 9.0f / 5i << endl;
```

The result yields `1`. I wonder why? Are there different rules or mechanism behind it?

Comment: How did you even get it to compile? `i` is not a built-in numeric suffix (in particular, it doesn't stand for `int` as you seem to believe). For this to compile, there must be an `operator"" i()` defined somewhere in your program; find it, see what it does.

Comment: `5i` is an imaginary number (i.e., complex number 0 + 5i) not integral 5.

Comment: @40two not out of the box. The compiler does not know what to do with `5i` as Igor said.

Comment: @tgmath it seems in Clang v3.4, not necessarily http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60abcb7c6b065585

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think I misunderstood the 'i'. Thx for that. But truth to be told, I have no other `operator"" i()` in the test.cpp. I simply include `iostream` and use the line directly.

Comment: @40two I don't get how to use this. `5i` is printed as `1` and an assignment to a complex sets it to `(0,0)` See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b7cea5e012ef911

Comment: @tgmath `std::cout` does not have an overload for `_Complex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `i` as a suffix is [an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html)  which indicates an imaginary constant as opposed to an integer that is also supported by `gcc`. Without warnings enables `clang` will just interpret `5i` as a complex number. With warning turned on(*specifically -Wconversion*) it gives the following warning:

```
warning: imaginary constants are a GNU extension [-Wgnu-imaginary-constant]
std::cout << 9.0f / 5i << std::endl;
                    ^

warning: implicit conversion discards imaginary component: '_Complex float' to 'bool' [-Wconversion]
std::cout << 9.0f / 5i << std::endl;
~~~          ~~~~~^~~~
```

So it looks like there is no overload for `_Complex` so the result is being converted to *bool*. We can see this more clearly using the following examples:

```
float f = (9.0f / 5 + 0i) ;
std::cout << f << std::endl ;
```

which outputs `1.8`.

If you just want an *int* literal then no suffix is needed, the other integral suffixes are `u, l, ul, ll, ull` for `unsigned, long, unsigned long, long long and unsigned long long` respectively.

So in your case:

```
9.0f / 5
```

would be what you want if you want to insure `9.0` is interpreted as a *float* otherwise it will be interpreted as a *double*.

`5` will be converted to a *float* as well since the `/` operator will perform the *usual arithmetic conversions* on it's operands.